# Laravel Cache (Redis) auto refresh when data is changed

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have some data in model. When data is being insert or delete how can i update the redis cache. Is there any way we can update the cache or 3rd party package

Comment: You could use [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) if you use eloquent to update single models. Beyond that there's no built-in automatic solution.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest option, in my opinion, would be setting an observer on the model and updating the data.

Eloquent Observers docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

Answer (score 1):

You just simple need to fire command

```
FLUSHALL
```

and put data back to keys again.

The package you are looking for is

```
composer require predis/predis
```

Here is official laravel documentation for [redis cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis#predis).

Comment: So basically, this means deleting the previous cache and creating the new one.? Right?